# dotCover error "Invalid counter encoding" on processing coverage results

Tags: .net, jetbrains-ide, dotcover

When running all unit tests (xUnit) with coverage using dotCover on a particular solution I'm getting the following error after all the tests pass in the Coverage tab: "Failed to process coverage results.  Invalid counter encoding".

I've tried closing VS, deleting everything in: `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\JetBrains`, then reopening the solution in VS and running tests/coverage and this fixes the problem the first time!  But subsequent restarts of VS and coverage runs fail with the error message.

I have yet to see this problem with any other solution.

So...

- What does "Invalid counter encoding" mean?
- Any ideas what I can do to permanently fix this? (part from deleting the cache before starting VS every time).

I'm running: JetBrains Ultimate 2017.3.5 on VS 2017 (15.5.7)